# How to convert JMeter results TimeStamp from scientific notation to valid Date time format

Tags: jmeter

I executed a smoke test on 23/02/2023 at 12:27:00. I get the the results in Excel .CSV file with columns like TimeStamp, elasped, Response Message and etc. I am trying to convert this timestamp from exponential notation (1.67716E+12) to a valid date time format like '23 Feb 2023 12:27:00' or at least only the time. When I place the cursor on the exponential notation, the number displayed is 1677155220544 - I am not sure how this is related to the time which the test was run (23/02/2023 at 12:27:00).

Please could someone suggest?
Thanks,
N

Answer (score 0):

This is co called [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), the number of milliseconds from 1st of Jan 1970.

If you want it to be "valid" - it's controllable by `jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format` [JMeter Property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

If you want it do look like `23/02/2023 at 12:27:00` you can add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I tried to browse the file via Aggregate Report listener but it is throwing an error:  Error parsing field 'timeStamp' at line 2. java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1677155546493"

Comment: Will try your suggestion..